# How can I generate scripts from a javascript file?

Tags: javascript

I want to generate scripts with specified functions from another javascript file. I don't know if is it possible ?

Comment: What kind of scripts you want to generate from javascript file, please provide an example here.

Comment: A skeleton like that : function start() { } function update() { } function stop {} and that's all. I have actors and I want to create a script behavior to attach to each one of them

Comment: When you say generate scripts do you mean like a screenplay script? What JavaScript file would you be referring to? Are you referring to a framework such as jQuery which you need to use its functionality on your page?

Comment: yes ! I would to generate screenplay like in Unity for each actor and find it in my directory. I'm not using jQuery I'm using a "classical javascript file that I call from an html page.

Comment: After looking at your JScript (IE's version of JavaScript), I see you're using `new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` to create a file onto your desktop locally. If you want to be able to simply create files the user can download without server interaction, you could use [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify). HTML5 also has a way to do this: [using Blob and createObjectURL](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html) which despite the page's "browser support" section also works in IE 11 for me locally, and should work in 10 as well.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It finally works ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Now I have this code that doesn't work and it should work only with internet explorer :

```
     function createFile() // genere un script pour chaque acteur
{
        alert("on rentre");
        var myObject, newfile;
        myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        newfile = myObject.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\NLJ1\Desktop\Stage_total\Stage_total\Stage\Scripts\Version_reconnaissance_fichier_extension\text.js", true);
        alert("on sort");
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, please edit your question instead.

Comment: Excuse me I didn't know